# Add elements from one array to another array one at a time

Tags: matlab

If I have an array

```
A = [2 4 6 8]
```

and another array

```
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

then I want to take the  first element of `A`, that is `2`, and add it each element of `B` and save the resultant array to a matrix `C`.
Next, I want to take `4`, add it to each element of `B` and again save it to `C`.
Similarly, for `6` and `8` elements, the same procedure is repeated.

How can I obtain the matrix `C` without using loops?

```
C = [(3 4 5 6 7 8 9)' (5 6 7 8 9 10 11)'  (7 8 9 10 11 12 13)'  (9 10 11 12 13 14 15)']
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 6):

Just use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
>> C = bsxfun(@plus, A, B.')

C =

     3     5     7     9
     4     6     8    10
     5     7     9    11
     6     8    10    12
     7     9    11    13
     8    10    12    14
     9    11    13    15
```

Comment: thanks. What if I want to choose the elements of `A` in any order and not in the order shown, can `bxsfun` allow that? Or should I first order them in the sequence I want? Example, instead of 2,4,6,8...can `bxsfun` be used to choose 4,2,8,6->in this order?

Comment: @nashynash reorder `A` yourself of course. Why would `bsxfun` be able to do that?. But it is trivial thing to do in MATLAB: `bsxfun(@plus, A([2,1,4,3]),B)`

Comment: You don't really need the `.'` for real numbers, `'` is enough :)

Comment: @Dan Okay. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bernhard who says the numbers are always going to be real. `.'` is transpose which is what we are doing here. Even though it gives the same result, technically we are not looking for a complex conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to tile and do it at once. For this you have many options depending on the argument size or memory constraints or in place overwriting freedom etc.

One way to replicate an array is providing a outer (also called dyadic or 1-rank so on) product

So when you perform the following multiplication:

```
[1]
[1]    
[1] * [a b c ... ]
[1]
[1]
```

the result is a rank 1 matrix with same rows

```
[a b c ... ]
[a b c ... ]
[a b c ... ]
[a b c ... ]
[a b c ... ]
```

The same thing you can do with the matlab function `repmat` which repeats an array in a much more general way and relies on `bsxfun` internally. Here a simple version of it is sufficient.

```
# repmat(A,number of repetitions vertically,number of repetitions horizontally)
repmat([a b c ...]',1,n)
```

gives again the same thing say for `n=4`

```
[a a a a]
[b b b b]
[c c c c]
    .
    .
    .
```

also you can use `kron` which is the Kronecker product implemented via `meshgrid` and hence essentially 2D (in a nutshell tile the second argument with each tile multiplied with the element of first argument)

```
kron([1;1;1;1;1],[a b c d e])
```

which gives the same result with the first argument. Now you can see that depending on the size of the argument or the amount of temporary arrays that are created you can have a cocktail of these methods although they perform the same operations. For example; two equivalent commands that differ internally are

```
C = ones(length(B),1)*A + repmat(B',1,length(A));
```

and

```
C = kron(ones(length(B),1),A) + kron(ones(1,length(A)),B')
```

Hence depending on the size of A and B you might benefit from these alternatives should you require that much of high performance. So half of the operation can be done in one way and the other part in another. It is an art rather that science. However, at these sizes they are rather minute differences.

Comment: why mix the methods? You could have just gone `C = ones(length(B),1)*A + B.'*ones(1,length(A));` I highly doubt `repmat` will outperform matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Dan Just to show possibilities. They don't differ too much in speed at these sizes.

Comment: I think this is confusing. If you want to show possibilities then rather write out the two methods separately. But mixing them just means anyone reading the code has to figure out what each term is doing separately and then potentially go on a wild goose chase trying to figure out why `*` is good for the first term but `repmat` is better for the second...

Comment: @Dan They represent the same operation. There is no ambiguity. I don't think anybody goes on a wild goose chase for a mere column repetition especially if you evaluate that part in isolation. It is a one line of code not rocket science

Comment: Imagine coming across this code: `A = B + C + plus(D,E)`. Sure this is equivalent to `A = B + C + D + E` but if you came across this you would pause to question why the developer chose to perform the last addition differently because if there is no reason then why would someone do that? Switching styles in the middle of an operation *is* confusing and if I came across code like that I would certainly try find out why it was done that way because I would assume no one would purposefully write code to confuse people. Especially someone not familiar with either method.

Comment: @Dan You assume that these are different things. They are not. They map the same arguments to same outputs. It's not to confuse people given that I've written that **they are essentially the same** up to implementation of these methods. If somebody gets confused they can read these comments now. Notice that not everybody needs to know numerical computing or C-majorization etc. see what these are actually doing. Not having a reason does not automatically imply confusion. I don't even know what we are discussing right now. They are basically different ways allocating the same array of numbers.

Comment: I am well aware that they do they same thing. I'm not going to argue any further. Switching styles mid-project is bad practice but switching mid-line is indefensible. Is there a benefit to what you've done? No. Is there a drawback? Yes, no matter how insignificant you may think it is. Anyone asking this question clearly doesn't know about `repmat` and has not thought about using matrix multiplication in this context and at first glance your answer is telling them they need both. But they don't. They need one or the other. You don't have a character limit so why not just include both options?

Comment: @Dan Again, there is no style here. I'm not switching from OOP to functional programming. They are different functions that do the same thing. I wish someone taught me `repmat` earlier in my career for example. Also they have different runtime profiles depending on the arguments and so on. It's a matter of choice. I'm not imposing any choice they are there anybody can decide for themselves. I'm not teaching anything here.

Comment: But let me take out the choice part out so it is more obvious